# Увеличение изображения на весь экран нахождения в списке

Tags: android, recyclerview, imageview

Есть у меня список(RecyclerView) картинок и текст. По нажатию на элемент обрабатывать событие. Чтоб картинка увеличивалась почти на весь экран и с текстом снизу. Еще один щелчок и возвращалось назад к списку. На картинках показал какой эффект хотелось бы добиться. Возможно кто-то делал, или знает какую библиотеку можно использовать.

Есть идея использовать диалоговый фрагмент. Ну может есть по лучше реализации?

Пробовал использовать библиотеку [ImageViewZoom](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/continuous-shared-element-transitions.html

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо. Это то что нужно. Буду разбираться и реализовывать. Сделайте как ответ, я отмечу

Comment: ссылка в качестве ответа - плохой ответ, а переписывать все, что там есть, мне что то не очень хочется :). Может кто то что то лучше предложит еще  ...